# Is a firewall needed on a small office that simply needs internet access?

Tags: firewalls

I'm planning on porting all of my office's software needs to cloud services that I can access via internet. It's a simple LAN that has a NAT gateway pointing to the open internet.

Would a firewall give me any benefits in this use case? What am I defending against?

Comment: You say you have a "NAT gateway", which by definition _is_ a firewall. What specifically do you need?

Comment: The NAT gateway is actually my ISP's modem which is also a router. I'm insecure about making the decision of dumping my enterprise firewall service, which is expensive and seems to add no value in this scenario. But then again, I might be wrong, hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm planning on porting all of my office's software needs to cloud services that I can access via internet.

If you don't want to deal with IT security, then moving all your critical systems to <strike>the cloud</strike> other people's servers can be a good idea. It greatly reduces the attack surface and value of your own computer systems. But only under the condition that you trust the people whose servers you use and are convinced that they know more about IT security than you do. We don't know whose servers you want to use, and whether or not you trust them is a judgement call you need to do on your own.

> It's a simple LAN that has a NAT gateway pointing to the open internet. Would a firewall give me any benefits in this use case?

A router performing NAT is already a kind of firewall, because any incomming connections won't reach any computers behind the router, unless the router explicitly set up port forwarding for that specific service.

Further, todays operating systems are a lot more secure than they used to be 20 years ago. You can usually assume that a properly patched and configured Windows 10, macOS or Linux machine exposed directly to the Internet won't get compromised that easily. So unless you have reasons to employ a higher security standard than usual, additional protective measures are unnecessary. We don't know in what line of business you are, so we can not tell you if you do.

> What am I defending against?

Assuming that you aren't doing anything which makes you a target for targeted attacks, just the usual stuff:

- Bots trying to run exploits via network
- Emails with viruses and phishing attempts
- Websites containing malicious code or trying to trick users into installing malware

The largest threat for a small business today is often [ransomware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware) - viruses which encrypt your files and expect you to pay for the decryption key (which might or might not work). The best counter-measure for this are regular backups, because those allow you to restore those files on your own. Moving all your files to other people's servers is not always a proper protection, because there are ransomwares which check that, will access those files in the same way you do and encrypt them too. See if the people whose servers you use offer a backup solution which will work in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer with incomplete data from my side. The "cloud" are either G Suite or Office 365 ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care what your internal users connect to on the Internet then a simple NAT device would be an effective firewall.

If you want to open up internal services to the Internet, you would then need a more advanced system.

If you want to monitor your internal network for potential malware you would need additional systems like a firewall or an IDS/IPS or some desktop level software like AV or Tanium.